# Реализация интерфейса IComparable для структуры

Tags: c#, интерфейс

Необходимо:

Создать список структур.

Параметры в открытый конструктор структуры передавать через кортеж (tuple).

Например:

```
(STUDENT S = new STUDENT (new Tuple< string, string,int []> ("FIO", 
  "GROUP",  new int[] {2,2,2,2,2} ));
```

Произвести сортировку, используя интерфейс `ICompareble` по разным полям.

И если с первыми двумя задачами я справился, то как реализовать интерфейс так, чтобы была возможна сортировка по разным полям не понимаю.

Comment: Не очень понятно, что в данном случае означает сортировку по разным полям. Возможно, что при реализации метод `CompareTo` должен учитывать несколько полей во время сортировки. К примеру, при одинаковом FIO сортировать дальше еще и по GROUP.

Comment: Нет, просто сортировка должна производиться по каждому из трёх полей независимо от другого так скажем)

Comment: Тогда интерфейс IComparable вам тут не поможет. Для сортировки по различным полям используются обычно IComparer или прямая передача в функцию Sort делегата Comparison.

Comment: Ну есть конечно вариант поизвращаться и сделать в классе дополнительное поле, которое будет учитывать IComparable и производить сортировку по нему, но это что-то из ряда вон выходящее и ненужное.

Comment: Спасибо)) Да, я разобрался, действительно IComparer нужно использовать)